# Match digits and still display the text

Tags: regex, perl

I have a textfile with results and attendances from various football games. I want to find each number and replace them with a phrase, as well as display the whole textfile.

`if($_ =~ s/\d{1,}/TEST/)` is my current regex, but it does not find floatnumbers. Any ideas?

Comment: Use `[\d.]+` to match digits and decimal points.

Comment: @Barmar: that also matches a single period (or any sequence of them). Some examples, please? It's easier when all of your floats have leading digits (`0.1`), for example, and/or you need the period in `100.`

Answer (score 0):

I'd use that one:

```
[-+]?\d+\.?\d*
```

It takes into account that a number maybe negative. If is not your case, remove the `[-+]?`